# Based on prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have a problem...

If  $A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}a(n)$ where $a(n)=\frac{1}{k}$ if $n=p^{k}$ and $a(n)=0$ in other case, show that $A(x)=\pi(x)+O(\sqrt{x}\:log\:logx)$

I think I should use the theorem of prime numbers, but I don't know how.
\\
is it possible to do it without the theorem?

Comment: $A(x)$ Is typically referred to as $\Pi(x)$ and is known as the Riemann prime counting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A(x)=\sum_{p^k\leq x}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{p\leq x}1+\sum_{p^2\leq x}\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{p^3\leq x}\frac{1}{3}\cdots$$
$$=\sum_{p\leq x}1+\sum_{p\leq x^{1/2}}\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{p\leq x^{1/3}}\frac{1}{3}+\cdots$$
$$=\pi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\pi(x^{1/2})+\frac{1}{3}\pi(x^{1/3})+\cdots$$
$$=\pi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\pi(x^{1/2})+\sum_{3\leq k \leq \log_2(x)}\frac{1}{k}\pi(x^{1/k})$$
$$=\pi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\pi(x^{1/2})+O(x^{1/3}\ln(x))$$
$$=\pi(x)+O(x^{1/2})=\pi(x)+O(x^{1/2}\ln(\ln(x)))$$

Comment: And note that this proof doesn't require the prime number theorem, just the trivial estimate $\pi(y) = O(y)$.

Comment: Why does the $log_{2}(x)$ appear? what happen later?

Comment: @user144507 $$A(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{\lg(x)}\rfloor}\frac{1}{k}\pi(x^{1/k})$$ Once $k$ exceeds $\lfloor{\lg(x)}\rfloor$ all proceeding values of $\pi(x)$ are zero. This is because of the fact that $1=\pi(2)=\pi(x^{1/\lg(x)})\leq\pi(x^{1/\lfloor{\lg(x)}\rfloor})$